# Moving a file in C

Tags: c, file

Is there a way to move a file into a folder in C? I have a program to create a folder but how would i be able to move a file to this folder?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string.h>

   void main()
{
    int check;
    char* dirname = "Key Items";
    system("cls");

    check = mkdir(dirname);

    // check if directory is created or not
    if (!check)
        printf("Directory created\n");
    else {
        printf("Unable to create directory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    getch();

    system("dir/p");
    getch();

}
```

Comment: Searching for "C rename file" turned up nothing?

Comment: If i rename it, it would be me creating a duplicate of it moving it towards the new file path correct?

Comment: Depends if it's on the same filesystem or not.

Comment: ill give it a shot and test it, thanks

Comment: You can have a look to mv source code: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/mv.c